# SQL Server - split each table row by fixed delimiter

Tags: sql-server

Having the string "abcd|efg|hijkl" I need to split it to three following values: "abcd", "efg" and "hijkl". That is pretty simple - considering that delimiter can vary its place, the following code will work:

```
DECLARE @id VARCHAR(100), @line1 INT, @line2 INT
SET @id = 'abcd|efg|hijkl'
SET @line1 = (SELECT CHARINDEX('|', @id))+1
SET @line2 = (SELECT CHARINDEX('|', @id, CHARINDEX('|', @id)+1))

SELECT LEFT(@id, CHARINDEX('|', @id)-1) AS First
  ,SUBSTRING(@id, @line1, @line2-@line1) AS Middle
  ,SUBSTRING(@id, @line2+1, len(@id)-@line2) AS Last
```

Now, suppose I have a table of similar strings and I want to retrieve the table consisting of columns 'First', 'Middle' and 'Last', each of them having appropriate value.
I know I could substitute @line1 and @line2 into select query, but the code won't be readable any more... How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `outer apply` to store intermediate calcutations results (supposing here column has name `id` too):

```
select
    LEFT(id, CHARINDEX('|', id)-1) AS First
    ,SUBSTRING(id, line1.Value, line2.Value - line1.Value) AS Middle
    ,SUBSTRING(id, line2.Value + 1, len(id) - line2.Value) AS Last
from your_table
    outer apply (SELECT CHARINDEX('|', id) + 1 as Value) as line1
    outer apply (SELECT CHARINDEX('|', id, CHARINDEX('|', id) + 1) as Value) as line2
```

This will prevent multiple copy-pasting of the same expressions and your code will remain readable.

Comment: thank you for quick answer! the only thing is that the last line needs to look like the following one: outer apply (SELECT CHARINDEX('|', Id, CHARINDEX('|', Id)+1) as Value) as line2 - this would return valid result. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, missed correct place of last bracket. You're right.

Answer (score 1):

Try This Code once By using **XML**:

**Temporary table with sample values**:

```
create table #YOUR_TABLE
    (
    [Name] varchar(100)
    )

    insert into #YOUR_TABLE values('abcd|efg|hijkl'),('a|e|hij')
```

**Query for Required output using XML:**

```
DECLARE @delimiter VARCHAR(100)

SET @delimiter='|' --IN This Variable you can change your required delimeter
;

WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT [Name],
                Cast('<M>'
                     + Replace([Name], @delimiter, '</M><M>')
                     + '</M>' AS XML) AS [Name XML]
         FROM   #YOUR_TABLE)
SELECT [Name],
       [Name XML].value('/M[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS [First Name],
       [Name XML].value('/M[2]', 'varchar(100)') AS [Middle Name],
       [Name XML].value('/M[3]', 'varchar(100)') AS [Last Name]
FROM   CTE
```

**Output**:

```
Name            First Name  Middle Name Last Name
abcd|efg|hijkl   abcd        efg          hijkl
a|e|hij          a           e            hij
```

Here the first step would be to convert that string into XML and replace the delimiter(i.e '|' in your case  with some start and end XML tags.Here i replaced delimeter into '' tags.

Answer (score 1):

If there is always 3 strings then you can use `PARSENAME` function for this:

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(100) = 'abcd|efg|hijkl'

SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE(@s, '|', '.'), 3),
       PARSENAME(REPLACE(@s, '|', '.'), 2),
       PARSENAME(REPLACE(@s, '|', '.'), 1)
```

Comment: Elegant solution. Thanks for sharing this idea.